# iFrame height not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Could not set IFrame height to 100% in IE and FF, but works fine in chrome, please find the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/3LAat/34/.
Below is the sample code:

```
   <body style="height:100%;width:100%">
 <div class="div_iframe">
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" style="border:0;" id="id" class="restricted" scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

How can i increase IFrame height to 100% to make it work in all browsers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
html { height: 100%; }
```

into your css: http://jsfiddle.net/3LAat/35/

Comment: It works in fiddle but when i kept the same in my application, it is not working, height is not increasing in IE and FF. @Daniel Stanley.

Comment: Have you got a live page I can look at?